# Default packages for all versions in asdf

Tags: asdf, asdf-vm

On all versions of node I use pm2, yarn, and a few others, and on PHP, I use xdebug, LDAP, and others is there a hook or file where I can define all the packages for the plugin to be installed when I install a new version of nodejs or PHP?

I would like to run `asdf install nodejs 12.0.4` for example and it tries to run something like `npm install -g yarn pm2` for me. Even if there's a hook file or anything that I can use, that would be amazing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such feature like that. If you would like to suggest a feature to the developers, please post an issue on the tracker: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can setup default npm packages.

`asdf-nodejs` can automatically install a set of default set of npm package right after installing a Node.js version. To enable this feature, provide a `$HOME/.default-npm-packages` file that lists one package per line, for example:

```
lodash
request
express
```

You can specify a non-default location of this file by setting a `ASDF_NPM_DEFAULT_PACKAGES_FILE` variable.

Source: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs#default-npm-packages